# Select the latest year in a column using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataframe like this

| Value. | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 08/08/2009 |
| A | 09/12/2021 |
| A | 05/10/2022 |
| A | 06/09/2022 |
| A | 07/08/2022 |

I need output like

| VALUE | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 05/10/2022 |
| A | 06/09/2022 |
| A | 07/08/2022 |

We have to print a latest year with all month data present in the date column .please refer output table.

i used SQL query like

Select Top 10 *  from table where
Order by (Date) DESC;

The max() select only one date so that didn't help me

But didn't get expected answer.
Can please someone help me with the query ?

Comment: what was the output of this query `Select Top 10 * from table where Order by (Date) DESC;`

Comment: I used Same query but didn't give expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `MAX` in a subquery, this will produce the intended outcome you have shown in your question:

```
SELECT yourcolumn
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
YEAR(yourcolumn) = (SELECT MAX(YEAR(yourcolumn)) FROM yourtable);
```

The latest year is 2022, so `MAX` in the subquery will find this year and the whole query will select all dates in 2022.

Comment: Fullscan. Slow..

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE datecolumn >= (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(datecolumn), '%Y-01-01')
                     FROM tablename)
```

To improve this query you'd have an index by `datecolumn` (or where this column is an expression prefix).

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Understood your point